# Auto Launched flow running in User mode

Tags: visual-workflow, customer-community, field-service-lightning

We have an auto launched flow which whenever a work order is rejected by a tech, it auto-dispatches work order to another available tech. We're calling the auto launched flow through a process builder which is trigger by a field update when the WO is rejected.

The auto dispatch is working great if the WO is rejected by an internal CSR on behalf of the service provider but when the service provider rejects, it is not auto dispatching. It feels like the auto launched flow is respecting the permissions and access of the service provider instead of running in system mode.  I tried multiple ways but with no success. How do I make sure to run it in system mode but not in user mode?

Here's how the process works: Service Provider Rejects a WO by clicking on Reject button in the community which calls an on screen flow where he specifies the reason for his rejection. I have an invocable apex action at end of the flow which updates the field, which triggers the process builder which then calls an auto launched which dispatches the work order. Everything works well If user is a CSR but not when the user is a Service Provider. I'm using without sharing keyword as well.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you are using Auto-launched and Screen flows. These can be run with one of three different contexts.

From inside your Flow, click the "View Properties" cogwheel, and then the "Show Advanced" link. You want to adjust the "How to Run the Flow".

Context options are:

1. User or System Context—Depends on How Flow is Launched.
2. System Context with Sharing—Enforces Record-Level Access.
3. System Context Without Sharing—Access All Data.

Don't give more permission than you need to. Try option 2 and see if that resolves your permissions issue. Option 3 should be a last resort especially if you are exposing this Flow to External Users.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using flow, it will respect user permissions. If you were to invoke a visual flow instead and use invokable APEX you could get around this and run in system mode using the `without sharing` keyword on the class.

But what I think is the best approach in this use case would be to use a visual flow and use a session based permission set that gets activated only for the step where the auto dispatch is supposed to fire. I prefer this approach because it further clarifies the intention of those implementing this solution --> the `without sharing` notation on the apex class could be there for many reasons and without any explanation.

Comment: Hello Glen, Thank you for the response. I tried these steps as well. Here's the process flow:
Service Provider Rejects a WO by clicking on Reject button in the community which calls an on screen flow where he specifies the reason for his rejection.

I have an invocable apex action at end of the flow which updates the field, which triggers the process builder which then calls an auto launched which dispatches the work order. Everything works well If user is a CSR but not when the user is a Service Provider. I'm using without sharing keyword as well.

Comment: @TonySF - please use [edit] on your original question to amend with these extra details

Comment: Remember that Auto-launched Flow can now be configured to run in full System Mode "System Context without Sharing - Access All Data". It is not the case that ... "Because you are using flow, it will respect user permissions."